# Query to get values and sum of attributes

Tags: sql-server, join

I'm trying to write a query but getting an error for finding sum of weights and volume:
SQL Error [8120] [S0001]: Column 'Attribute.attribute_value' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
  com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Column 'Attribute.attribute_value' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

```
  SELECT
    dg.delivery_group_id, 
     ctr.container_type, 
    ven.attribute_value AS 'vendor',
    carr.attribute_value AS 'carrier',
    com.attribute_value AS 'commodity',
    conv.attribute_value AS 'conveyance',
    stor.attribute_value AS 'store',
    SUM(ISNULL(CAST(wgt.attribute_value AS float), 0.0)) AS 'weight',
    SUM(ISNULL(CAST(vol.attribute_value AS float), 0.0)) AS 'volume'

    FROM (SELECT
    pal.container_id AS 'container_id',
    pal.container_type AS container_type,
    cas.container_id AS 'sub_container_id',
    pal.loc_id
    FROM container pal
    LEFT OUTER JOIN container cas
    ON cas.parent_container_id = pal.container_id
    AND cas.container_type = 'Case'
    WHERE pal.container_type = 'Pallet') AS ctr
    INNER JOIN Container_Detail cdtl
    ON (ctr.container_id = cdtl.container_id
    OR ctr.sub_container_id = cdtl.container_id)
   INNER JOIN container_delivery cd
   ON cdtl.detail_id = cd.detail_id 
   INNER JOIN delivery_line dl
   ON cd.delivery_line_id = dl.delivery_line_id
   INNER JOIN delivery_group dg
   ON dl.delivery_group_id = dg.delivery_group_id
   INNER JOIN Attribute ven 
   ON cdtl.attribute_id=ven.attribute_id AND ven.attribute_type='vendor'
   INNER JOIN Attribute carr 
    ON cdtl.attribute_id=carr.attribute_id AND carr.attribute_type='carrier'
   INNER JOIN Attribute com 
    ON cdtl.attribute_id=com.attribute_id AND com.attribute_type='commodity'
   INNER JOIN Attribute conv 
    ON cdtl.attribute_id=conv.attribute_id AND     
    conv.attribute_type='conveyance'   
    INNER JOIN Attribute stor 
    ON cdtl.attribute_id=stor.attribute_id AND stor.attribute_type='store'
    INNER JOIN Attribute wgt 
    ON cdtl.attribute_id=wgt.attribute_id AND wgt.attribute_type='weight'
    INNER JOIN Attribute vol 
    ON cdtl.attribute_id=vol.attribute_id AND vol.attribute_type='volume'
   WHERE ctr.container_id = '00007712120038613557'
    OR ctr.sub_container_id = '00007712120038613557'
     GROUP BY dg.delivery_group_id,    
        ctr.container_type,ctr.container_id,ctr.sub_container_id,    
        wgt.attribute_value, vol.attribute_value
```

Following is my table :
[image]

Comment: you have to add all select column to group by clause except column on which inbuilt functions(sum) are used .

Comment: @SanjayPatel can u please provide the query with the change u just said

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add all of these to your group by:

```
group by     dg.delivery_group_id, 
     ctr.container_type, 
    ven.attribute_value AS,
    carr.attribute_value ,
    com.attribute_value AS ,
    conv.attribute_value ,
    stor.attribute_value
```

Comment: what about weight and volume?

Comment: ideally you woulnd't need those 2 as thet are included in the sum function, but if you got an error with my group by condition, the try adding those two to see how it changes.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
    dg.delivery_group_id, 
     ctr.container_type, 
    ven.attribute_value AS 'vendor',
    carr.attribute_value AS 'carrier',
    com.attribute_value AS 'commodity',
    conv.attribute_value AS 'conveyance',
    stor.attribute_value AS 'store',
    SUM(ISNULL(CAST(wgt.attribute_value AS float), 0.0)) AS 'weight',
    SUM(ISNULL(CAST(vol.attribute_value AS float), 0.0)) AS 'volume'

    FROM (SELECT   pal.container_id AS 'container_id',  

      pal.container_type AS container_type,    cas.container_id AS 'sub_container_id',     pal.loc_id    FROM container pal    LEFT OUTER JOIN container cas    ON cas.parent_container_id = pal.container_id
        AND cas.container_type = 'Case'      WHERE pal.container_type = 'Pallet') AS ctr     INNER JOIN Container_Detail cdtl     ON (ctr.container_id = cdtl.container_id     OR ctr.sub_container_id = cdtl.container_id)    INNER JOIN container_delivery cd
       ON cdtl.detail_id = cd.detail_id     INNER JOIN delivery_line dl    ON cd.delivery_line_id = dl.delivery_line_id    INNER JOIN delivery_group dg    ON dl.delivery_group_id = dg.delivery_group_id    INNER JOIN Attribute ven 
       ON cdtl.attribute_id=ven.attribute_id AND ven.attribute_type='vendor'
       INNER JOIN Attribute carr 
        ON cdtl.attribute_id=carr.attribute_id AND carr.attribute_type='carrier'
       INNER JOIN Attribute com 
        ON cdtl.attribute_id=com.attribute_id AND com.attribute_type='commodity'
       INNER JOIN Attribute conv 
        ON cdtl.attribute_id=conv.attribute_id AND     
        conv.attribute_type='conveyance'   
        INNER JOIN Attribute stor 
        ON cdtl.attribute_id=stor.attribute_id AND stor.attribute_type='store'
        INNER JOIN Attribute wgt 
        ON cdtl.attribute_id=wgt.attribute_id AND wgt.attribute_type='weight'
        INNER JOIN Attribute vol 
        ON cdtl.attribute_id=vol.attribute_id AND vol.attribute_type='volume'
       WHERE ctr.container_id = '00007712120038613557'
        OR ctr.sub_container_id = '00007712120038613557'
         group by    
         dg.delivery_group_id, 
         ctr.container_type, 
        ven.attribute_value AS,
        carr.attribute_value ,
        com.attribute_value AS ,
        conv.attribute_value ,
        stor.attribute_value
```